# Color of Selected Item in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am writing **listView1.Items[1].Selected = true;**
but it does not highlight that item....what is wrong?
I also changed the HideSelection property to False, so now at least I can see some Gray highlight color, but where is the blue color?  when I click with Mouse, it is blue, but when I set it with code as posted above , it is not blue... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your Windows colors that are tricking you.
I just tested it, and with `HideSelection` set to false, I set the selected item, and I see that item turn grey, which is my Windows color definition for a selected item in an inactive control.
If you want it to turn blue, which is most likely the color of a selected item in an active control, set the focus to that `ListView`, saying `listView1.Focus()`, and you'll see that color you're talking about, but you've just changed the focus to it, so be careful.

Comment: Hmm, ok so why if I use a ListBOX,  I do not have this problem?

Comment: Well, it's technically not a "problem", it's just the way Microsoft decided to make it.  I'll ask Bill the next time I see him =)  The ListBox doesn't seem to care about the color of inactive control, it uses the active-control color all the time.  But very good attention to detail.

Comment: LOL! better to ask Hejlsberg! he was the chief architect!... unfortunately I cannot use "Focus" technique, because I am typing a search string inside a textbox and it highlighting the result in that ListView, so if I move the focus to the ListView, then the user cannot continue typing in the text Box :(

Comment: Yup, that's what I suspected; you don't want to transfer control to it.  But this simply tells you that to "highlight" something in the background, ListView would not be a good choice.  Sorry.

Comment: Does not work for me (VS 2013) while fab's code does, regardless of HideSelection setting.

Answer (score 2):

```
listView1.Select();
listView1.Items[index].Selected = true;
```